# What are the white nodules on my Peperomia Polybotrya, near where the leaves fell off?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, indoors, peperomia

I'm very new to indoor plants so thought I would ask some more experienced indoor gardeners as I am coming up empty after a few weeks of Google searching. I've had these small white nodules appear on the stems of my Peperomia Polybotrya, near where the leaves have fallen. Not sure exactly what they are, if they are caused by the recent seasonal change, or possibly exposure to recent construction (I have wiped the leaves down but not sure if I can do anything about the soil?) If anyone knows what these nodules are and how to fix them (if that even is a problem) it will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Peperomia Polybotrya Assistance]

Answer (score 1):

They are harmless.  They are sites where roots could grow and are called [adventitious roots](https://academic.oup.com/plphys/article/170/2/603/6114063?login=false). The definition from the article is

> plant roots that form from any nonroot tissue and are produced both
> during normal development ... and in response to stress conditions, such
> as flooding, nutrient deprivation, and wounding